# Cant use netaddr output List in function

Tags: networking, python-3.7

i'm newbie in Python. Trying to make a script to scan Subnet and use those address as a list in spreadsheet.

My code:

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import netaddr


List_IP = []

subnet = input("Please inter subnet mask:")

for ip in IPNetwork(subnet, implicit_prefix=True):
 
    str(ip)

    List_IP.append(ip)


print(List_IP)
print(type(List_IP))
```

So, the output if i use any subnet will be like this:

```
[IPAddress('3.555.5.550'), IPAddress('3.555.5.550'), IPAddress('3.555.5.550'), 
IPAddress('3.555.5.550')]
<class 'list'>
```

So, problem is i cant use this list in my function because it have those IPAddress. I need list with clear IPs like:

```
'3.555.5.550', '3.555.5.550'  and etc
```

I did try to strip list but it did not work.

Please help me and please understand that i'm a beginner :))

Answer (score 0):

as simple as it can be:

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import netaddr
from netaddr import IPSet


List_IP = []

subnet = input("Please inter subnet mask:")

for ip in IPNetwork(subnet):
    List_IP.append(str(ip))

print(List_IP)
```